# Temporarily Remove Or Hide Code in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to temporarily hide or remove a file from Intellij? I used to work in c# and I remember there was some way in visual studio to temporarily remove a project from the build then add it back later. I am just trying to figure out what parts of code are necessary for certain features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for `git stash`.

1. If you're not using a git repo, hit **Ctrl+Shift+A** and type "Create Git Repository", then hit enter to initialize git tracking on your current project.
2. Initially, you'll want to add your important files to git. Hit **Alt+1** to navigate to the Project View, then select all the files.
3. In order to add a file to git, press **Ctrl+Alt+A**, you should see the filename turn from red to green. It is now being tracked.
4. Now you'll want to make your first commit. Hit **Ctrl+K**, and IDEA will guide you through this.
5. Finally, once everything's all checked in, you can start messing around a little. If you make a few changes, say delete a file, and want to temporarily revert to the last commit, hit **Ctrl+Shift+A**, then "Stash". Select "Stash changes", write a little message for yourself, and you'll immediately jump back to the last commit.
6. Now say you want to go back to those changes you stashed. Hit **Ctrl+Shift+A** again, type "Unstash" then select "Unstash changes". Find the stash, check "Pop stash" and hit Enter.

This is a pretty common workflow for temporarily saving, removing and reverting changes in Git. You can read more about `git stash` [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/temporarily-stashing-your-work/), and [version control on IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvgoBMVPyFc) from Martin Balliauw.

Comment: Just to complete the answer, if you use an other versioning system, you can use the shelf feature. You'll need to go in Changes view (Alt+9), right click a file/change list in local tab and select shelf changes. You'll can retrieve shelfs in the Shelf tab. It's the same idea as a patch